# How do I lock header rows but allow creation of new rows using AXLSX?

Tags: axlsx

If I add sheet protection to my worksheet, and then unlock all but my header rows, it's almost working. But I'm not able to add new rows. I suspect it's because the default style for a worksheet is that cells are locked. What's the incantation to make cells be unlocked by default?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?